# Convert a dict to three-column dataframe using ID/key/value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere, but querying for it is a bit tricky.

I have a dict that's structured with an ID field and then 1-many key-value pairs
eg:

```
{ '123' : {'name': 'Joe', 'age': '17 },
  '888' : {'name': 'Cheryl', 'hometown': 'Liverpool'},
  '432' : {'name': 'Raj'}
 }
```

I want to get this into a SQL table structured as three columns: id | property-name | property-value, eg:

```
123 | name | Joe
123 | age  | 17
888 | name | Cheryl
888 | hometown | Liverpool
432 | name | Raj
```

My plan was to go through a pandas DataFrame, and then to_sql it.  The problem is creating a dataframe out of a dict tries to make the IDs column headers and every possible property name a row.

Question 1: Is the only way to convert my dict to a 3-col dataframe to loop through it, appending values to three arrays?

Question 2: Is it necessary to go through pandas at all?  Would it be better to just use sqlalchemy and fill in an INSERT query instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method of doing it using [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```
d = { '123' : {'name': 'Joe', 'age': '17'},
   '888' : {'name': 'Cheryl', 'hometown': 'Liverpool'},
   '432' : {'name': 'Raj'}
  }    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient = 'index').unstack().reset_index()
df
        level_0 level_1          0
    0      name     123        Joe
    1      name     432        Raj
    2      name     888     Cheryl
    3       age     123         17
    4       age     432        NaN
    5       age     888        NaN
    6  hometown     123        NaN
    7  hometown     432        NaN
    8  hometown     888  Liverpool
```

If you want to remove the NaN's, simply add `.dropna()` to the end of the statement.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient = 'index').unstack().reset_index().dropna()
df
        level_0 level_1          0
    0      name     123        Joe
    1      name     432        Raj
    2      name     888     Cheryl
    3       age     123         17
    8  hometown     888  Liverpool
```

Comment: brilliant!  though in my actual data there are dozens of property types (hurray user-generated fields).  Do I have to worry about any performance issues?

Comment: ha always fun when you're working with that type of data. I wish I had an   answer for you regarding speed of `from_dict` vs. @Wen 's answer. I will do some research and see if I can find an appropriate answer

Answer (score 1):

You can using `Series`

```
pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
Out[206]: 
  level_0   level_1          0
0     123       age         17
1     123      name        Joe
2     432      name        Raj
3     888  hometown  Liverpool
4     888      name     Cheryl
```